# How to read/write file as root using Kivy for Android?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I would like to write to /etc/hosts in my Kivy app, and I've surely a rooted device to test. I tried several ways but always get my app exit without any warning or error.

I've tried:

`subprocess.Popen("su -c touch /etc/hosts", shell = True)`

`subprocess.Popen("su -c bash -c touch /etc/hosts", shell = True)`

`subprocess.Popen(["su", "-c", "bash -c touch /etc/hosts"])`

and several combinations of them. Every time I can get the su app message box asking me for permission and I pressed "Allow", but my app exits after that.

**EDIT**: logcat output is at http://pastebin.com/YMT5Vxra

Many thanks if anyone can give any suggestion!

Comment: Do you have any code after that?  Try putting a 5 second wait after it with [```time.sleep(5)```](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep).  Your program might be exiting before ```touch``` finishes running.

Comment: The program is under Kivy Platform, I just bind this code to a button click event. But it just silently exits...

Comment: Can you post your log from "adb logcat" ? Kivy/Python will output an exception when something goes wrong

Comment: @tito Thank you! I've pasted the log now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error indicate that string-escape is not a known encoding. Kivy is shipping a lite version of Python with their libs, not all the encodings for example. What you can try is to:

- Grab python-for-android project
- Go into private/lib/encodings
- Copy the file from your computer to this directory (/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/string_escape.pyo)
- Rebuild your application

Then that should work.

The pgs4a-kivy project is not good as soon as kivy is not shipping the files you want. This is why i've started [python-for-android](http://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) project. You'll have the power of what you want or not in your final distribution.